# Dealing with service dependencies that time out or fail

Tags: windows-services

I have writen a windows service that overwrite Logon and Logoff methods of ISenesLogon2 to check out when logon and logoff occure and then insert the log information into the sql server on server computer.

But it has problem when i turn on the client computer just after the server.

In this situation my service could not insert in sql server.

I think it's because of that the sql server did not load completely before the winservice tried to access to it.

So i want to find a way to check programmatically if the sql server is ready and then try to work with?

Answer (score 1):

Your service cant start until its dependencies remote or otherwise have also started.  Checking SQL Server is easy, try and connect to it and retry until you succeed.

Only problem is services have timeouts on startup, you cant sit and repeat this indefinitely.

Things that cannot be reliably started in a reasonable timeframe should not be services or they should fail as soon as possible.  Otherwise you will end up with a lot of support requests for your service timing out.

Services are also usually not interactive to the user, so the failure is worse because you cant directly tell the user that your not up unless you do a tray icon.

Comment: Thanx, So you mean i does not a good idea to use windows service to save user logs? Which way do you sujest?

Comment: You can use a service, but if the backend is down you should have a strategy for queueing up log messages until its back up.  Otherwise your service will not respond due to timeouts trying to talk to SQL server.